# Why Wayland is using OpenGL ES instead of OpenGL?

Tags: linux, graphics, wayland

As far as I know, Wayland is not using OpenGL but OpenGL ES for 3D rendering, usually used on embedded systems (except for Intel IGPs). In the long term, I read that OpenGL support would be implemented but was not a priority for now.

I guess it is because OpenGL ES is somewhat simpler but it does not seems like a strong point for making such a choice.

I was wondering what were the reasons for this decision, and what were (and would be, for the future of Linux) the consequences of this choice.

#### Update:

The [Wayland FAQ](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/faq.html) was my fist stop before even thinking about asking it here. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong, but the last part seems, at least, not very clear, IMHO:

> EGL is the only GL binding API that lets us avoid dependencies on
>   existing window systems, in particular X.

As far as I understand, it's not that simple. EGL is an interface between GLs such as OpenGL **and** OpenGL ES. OpenGL ES calls are possible directly through Wayland/Weston while OpenGL support needs XWayland.

> GLX obviously pulls in X dependencies and only lets us set up GL on X drawables. The alternative is to write a Wayland specific GL binding API, say, WaylandGL.

So, this part refers to what I was saying above and, as far as I know, Wayland development team does not want to take that alternative route. So, for now, people willing to ports their applications which does not make direct use of Wayland/Weston are forced to translate their OpenGL API calls to OpenGL ES ones.

> A more subtle point is that libGL.so includes the GLX symbols, so
>   linking to that library will pull in all the X dependencies. This
>   means that we can't link to full GL without pulling in the client side
>   of X, so Weston uses OpenGL ES to render.

This seems understandable, on a short-time basis, at least. Still, on the long run, Wayland devlopment team wants to add OpenGL APIs as well, so it seems more like a workaround for now to me, until things get serious. This is one of the sentences which triggered my question here in the first place.

> As detailed above, clients are however free to use whichever rendering
>   API they like.

If I am not mistaken, which means going for XWayland for OpenGL applications and Weston OpenGL ES, which seems to be a bigger deal that what the sentence implies, especially when it comes to 3D rendering, not to mention the fact that Wayland/Weston aim to replace Xorg.

[For the record:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server#XWayland):

> XWayland is a series of patches over the X.Org server codebase that
>   implement an X server running upon the Wayland protocol. The patches
>   are developed and maintained by the Wayland developers for
>   compatibility with X11 applications during the transition to
>   Wayland,[28] and was mainlined in version 1.16 of the X.Org Server in
>   2014.When a user runs an X application from within Weston, it calls upon XWayland to service the request.

N.B.: I am trying to learn more about Wayland/Weston, especially when it comes to (3D) rendering, but exact information on this subject is diffcult to find, especially because it seems that the only people really X11-savvy seem to be Wayland developers.

As far as I can tell so far, for OpenGL:

- if OpenGL function calls are made through GLX interface, it falls back to XWayland, so the programme is (really) not using Wayland.

#### Addendum

It might seems that the discussion is out of the scope of the original question but it is actually linked to underlying OpenGL interfaces/libraries and it is difficult to separate all of this from the original question.

As it seems to be a complicated and confusing subject, here are some various links and quotes which lead me to think that OpenGL (not ES) is not *really* supported by Wayland per se, but falls back to X11, through XWayland:

[What does EGL do in the Wayland stack](https://ppaalanen.blogspot.com/2012/03/what-does-egl-do-in-wayland-stack.html)

> The Wayland server in the diagram is Weston with the DRM backend. The server > does its rendering using GL ES 2, which it initialises by calling EGL.

[Hacker News comments](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18255738)

> Wayland is actually pretty stable. Nvidia has problem with OpenGL in
>   Xwayland (i.e. 3d accel for x11 apps), otherwise, it should work.
>   There are warts though, when using Wayland. When using scaling
>   (doesn't have to be fractional, either), X11 apps are being upscaled,
>   not downscaled, resulting in blurriness. Unfortunately, neither
>   Firefox nor Chrome does support Wayland natively, and who wants to use
>   their most used app on their computer in blurry mode?

[How come GLX-based applications can be run on Wayland on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788578/how-come-glx-based-applications-can-be-run-on-wayland-on-ubuntu)

So based on the link @genpfault provided:

> So based on the link @genpfault provided:
>
> - XWayland is a part of XOrg that's providing an X server on top of Wayland. Any application that's linked against X11 libs and running
>     under Wayland will automatically use XWayland as its backend. So the
>     GLX part of XWayland is the mechanism that allows GLX-based OpenGL
>     applications to run on Wayland.
> - Not being able to use MSAA in GLX-based applications seems to be a known bug of XWayland, at least for Intel and AMD GPUs (cf.
>     https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98272 ). But I couldn't
>     find any additional information on the matter.

Comment: @sourcejedi I was not clear I guess. It's not contradictory if you read "direct use" as "without using XWayland".

Comment: I think this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10187032/799204 and "OpenGL is enabled by default" at https://www.mesa3d.org/egl.html .  I am guessing Mesa EGL supports `EGL_OPENGL_API`, because I don't know why it wouldn't.

Comment: So I searched "wayland opengl egl" - that did it.  Anyone care to write it up as a proper answer? The result was https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/7whgo0/opengl_context_in_wayland/du0uy7v/

Comment: @source jedi Sorry, I already saw/read all of these. But they do not answer the question. Or I missed really something when reading. Again, I do not see where there is any proof there is no lack of support of "classic" OpenGL, which leads to use XWayland. But again, my bad if I am missing something. Since 2014, the documentation and information are pretty dry and scarse, apart from bug fixing announcements, some distributions/DE making use of Wayland by default and users being mad for some reasons. Not to mention the phase where people were (are?) taking sides regarding Mir/Wayland/X11.

Comment: That is a buildable code example, and "it worked perfectly on my Debian Stable machine in X using the weston compositor from the repos".  I am not sure what more you could want!

Comment: @sourcejedi If you got this far, it is easy: (very) basically, just to know if EGL uses Wayland for OpenGL (not ES) or XWayland (so GLX/X11). For example, if you run, let's say, a game using OpenGL4, it falls back to XWayland, Wayland X11 clients compatibiliy layer. Regarding the link, I need to find some time to compile and run the example, even if I am sure of it would not give me a final answer, just a snapshot of the current status on my system, at this point of time.

Comment: BTW, the uncertainty on which underlaying OpenGL API being used was adressed by many projects along the years of Wayland development, such as [Waffle](https://github.com/waffle-gl/waffle), for example.

Comment: You said you read the example code.  See how it uses wayland handles, together with GL headers and library - not GLES.  There is absolutely no way it can be using X11.  If you want to look at an example of how a game is behaving, you should ask that as a separate question.  I don't know all the factors that would dictate what a game would do, but the most obvious is that Ubuntu is still on Wayland as of 18.10.  Why would you bother to test and expose yourself to anything with *less* market share than Ubuntu, if the compatibility mechanism works as well as you suggest?

Comment: @sourcejedi "There is absolutely no way it can be using X11." From what you have  shown, there is no hard evidence, because it's just "an abstraction" of what interface is really being used. I said game like I would have said anything else. "Being on Wayland" for a distro/DE does not mean much, this is what I am trying to explain.

Comment: @sourcejedi "Why would you bother to test and expose yourself to anything with less market share than Ubuntu, if the compatibility mechanism works as well as you suggest?" Remember Ubuntu was pushing Mir, with Nvidia backing them up? But Mir vs. Wayland is another story. Even if your argument is not the point here, it seems that it is less unlikely that you think it is. BTW, I did not suggest anything, but it is true that there is an overhead to run X11 applications (through XWayland) on Wayland.

Comment: "Using XWayland is just the same as [a modern composited X desktop], but **more** efficient because the compositing manager doesn't have to go back through the X server to display the content it rendered."

Comment: @sourcejedi Yes, sorry: I was not talking about the overhead of XWayland compared to X11, but compared to "native" Wayland. Regarding your previous message, like said, I will try that ASAP. But, as far a I can tell, this means it's not _really_ supported (yet?) but it's handled by a retro-compatibility layer to avoid X11-dependant applications to be unusable. And now we're back on tracks on my original question.

Answer (score 16):

The premise of your question is wrong. Wayland does not use OpenGL ES or OpenGL at all. Lets get things in order to achieve proper understanding of the software stack:

1. Wayland is an IPC protocol that allows the clients and the compositor to talk to each other. While technically libwayland is just a single implementation of that protocol and should not be solely identified with it, for now it remains the only implementation and is generally called 'wayland' as well. It is not a full compositor that runs your hardware.
2. Wayland Compositor is an application that uses wayland protocol to receive buffers from clients and compose it into a single image shown on the display. The wayland protocol makes relatively little assumptions about the inner workings of the compositor itself. In particular, the choice of the rendering technology is left completely open. The default buffer type defined by the core protocol is a simple shared memory buffer that is not accelerated by the GPU in any way, and is meant mainly for simple applications that render their UI using the CPU only. This buffer type is not interesting in our case, and will be conveniently forgotten in the rest of the answer.
3. Weston is a reference implementation of a wayland compositor. While it is developed by the people involved in the development of the libwayland itself, it is not an essential part of the wayland ecosystem - it is just a single compositor implementation. If you are running any of the Linux distributions that include wayland desktop environments, you are almost certainly not using Weston, but rather some other compositor implementation. Weston uses OpenGL ES for rendering - this is mainly dictated by the fact that the current libGL implementations still link to some X-related libraries, and Weston creators wanted to keep it pure wayland - this is a reference implementation after all. Additionally, it makes it compatible with the embedded devices, which may not support the full OpenGL.
4. EGL - libEGL is a library that contains glue-code that allows to initialize multiple rendering contexts of huge variety (OpenGL, OpenGL ES or OpenVG in different versions). It also allows sharing of data between such contexts - i.e. it allows to pass a framebuffer rendered with OpenGL and pass it to OpenVG for further processing. Sharing of these resources can occur across process boundaries - the receiver of a resource may be a different application than the process that has created it. A reference to a shared resource (buffer) can be passed between processes in a variety of ways, e.g. over a compatible wayland IPC connection. A buffer (EGL Image) passed in such a way does not retain any reference to the rendering API used to obtain it.
   While it is claimed that the EGL layer is also responsible for binding the framebuffers to the underlying OS elements like windows or displays, in practice that means sharing buffers with some system process that can use it to e.g. paint it in a window or on a particular display. Therefore, it is just a variation of the above functionality rather than a separate feature.
   The libEGL is heavily extensible, and there is a huge list of extensions available, so your libEGL implementation may be also responsible for other tasks, that do not fit the above description.
5. GLX - an older and more limited variant of the EGL. It allows sharing of the buffers of various kinds, but only between an X11 client and X11 server. It is inherently tied to the X11 protocol - if the client application uses X11 protocol,
   it can use GLX as well. If it uses wayland protocol, it cannot. EGL was developed as its replacement, to allow sharing of such data more generally. Modern X11 servers allow clients to use EGL instead of GLX as well.

So the wayland technology does not require you to use OpenGL ES, nor does it even vaguely point in its direction. **The reference compositor Weston uses it** internally, but that has no influence on the client rendering API. The only requirement is that whatever you render can be transformed into EGL Image. Since this is the job of libEGL, the choice of the rendering API on the client side is dictated only by the limitations of your libEGL implementation. This is also true for other compositors which may or may not be using OpenGL ES to render the final desktop image.

The libEGL is a part of the GPU driver software (just like e.g. libGL) so whether it allows converting OpenGL buffer into an EGL Image (and subsequently EGL Image to OpenGL ES texture on the compositor side) is dependent on your hardware, but in practice virtually every hardware allows that as long as it supports the full OpenGL at all. This is why you have difficulty finding the definitive proof that wayland supports the full OpenGL - wayland does not care about the rendering technology at all. Just as the FAQ says:

> What is the drawing API?
>
> "Whatever you want it to be, honey"[...]

Therefore, the question whether OpenGL is supported is out of scope for wayland. It is actually determined solely by the capabilities of the libEGL and the hardware.

The client application must use a particular API in order to initialize its windows and the GL(ES) contexts. If the client application uses X11 API to create its windows, then it will connect to the XWayland compatibility shim which pretends to be a full X11 server to the client. Then the client will be able to use either GLX or EGL-on-X11 to initialize its contexts and share rendered buffers with X11 server. If the client uses wayland client API to create its windows, it will be able to use the EGL-on-wayland to initialize its contexts and share rendered buffers with wayland compositor. This choice in most cases lies **entirely** on the client side.

A lot of older software that is not Wayland-aware uses just X11 API and GLX - simply because the wayland and EGL API did not exist (or was not mature enough) during the development. Even more modern software often uses just X11 API for compatibility reasons - there is still quite a lot non-wayland systems out there. Modern UI toolkits like GTK or QT actually support multiple "backends", which means that they can detect the session type on initialization and use the most appropriate API to create windows and drawing contexts. Since games generally don't use such toolkits, the burden of such detection falls entirely on their developers. Not many projects like that bother to actually implement it, and they often rely on X11 and GLX protocol on both X11 and wayland sessions (through Xwayland). So if you have a game uses GLX to initialize OpenGL means that it has opted to use X11 API. Whether this is because the game does not support wayland or EGL at all, or whether the game tried to use EGL to initialize OpenGL and failed for some reason I cannot judge without a ton of additional information. In any case, it is not in any way dependent on the wayland protocol or the used compositor.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the nvidia driver [originally](https://www.g-truc.net/post-0457.html) only supported ES as a "profile" of normal opengl. EGL came much later [instead](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ3NzA).

Comment: @mirh That driver version didn't really support wayland so it is not relavant to the discussion. And `EGL` and `OpenGL ES` are two completely different things that can be introduced separately - the EGL did not come instead of ES.

Comment: Yes, that was my point, to answer with a practical example to OP thinking GLES and EGL have some particular entailment.

Answer (score 1):

From https://wayland.freedesktop.org/faq.html:

> Why does Wayland use EGL?
>
> EGL is the only GL binding API that lets us avoid dependencies on
>   existing window systems, in particular X. GLX obviously pulls in X
>   dependencies and only lets us set up GL on X drawables. The
>   alternative is to write a Wayland specific GL binding API, say,
>   WaylandGL.
>
> A more subtle point is that libGL.so includes the GLX symbols, so
>   linking to that library will pull in all the X dependencies. This
>   means that we can't link to full GL without pulling in the client side
>   of X, so Weston uses OpenGL ES to render. This also enables Weston to
>   run on GPUs which don't support the full OpenGL API.
>
> As detailed above, clients are however free to use whichever rendering
>   API they like.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? I updated my question to mention that I already read this piece of documentation but I tried to address what was not clear about it.

Comment: 'What is the drawing API?

"Whatever you want it to be, honey". Wayland doesn't render on behalf of the clients, it expects the clients to use whatever means they prefer to render into a shareable buffer.'

Comment: Thanks but I already knew that. The problem is when you take a look at how Wayland handles EGL calls there seems to have a discrepancy between the APIs: AFAIK, OpenGL ES function calls are handled "natively" by Wayland, while "classic" OpenGL function calls fall back to X11 compatibility layer and therefore XWayland. Which leads me to think either OpenGL support is not coming to Wayland and has not come yet, which is my question. But, if I'm wrong or missing something, I'd like to see evidence of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the totality of the docs, some of which are quoted in other answers, is clear enough if you are willing to trust them all.  I admit... sometimes that strategy gives unreliable results :-).  So here is your "hard evidence".

Web search [wayland opengl egl]: ["Worked perfectly on my Debian Stable machine in X using the weston compositor from the repos"](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/7whgo0/opengl_context_in_wayland/du0uy7v/).

Here are the commands I recommended you run, as per my comments:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eyelash/tutorials/
cloning into 'tutorials'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 88, done.
remote: Total 88 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 88
Unpacking objects: 100% (88/88), done.
$ cd tutorials
$ gcc -o wayland-egl wayland-egl.c -lwayland-client -lwayland-egl -lEGL -lGL
```

`$ ./wayland-egl &    # a green square appears!
$ ss --unix -a -p | grep wayland-egl
u_str ESTAB  0      0                                                  * 3920430                                         * 3921234                               users:(("wayland-egl",pid=3260,fd=3))
$ ss --unix -a -p | grep 3921234
u_str ESTAB  0      0                           /run/user/1001/wayland-0 3921234                                         * 3920430                               users:(("gnome-shell",pid=2271,fd=100),("gnome-shell",pid=2271,fd=20))
u_str ESTAB  0      0                                                  * 3920430                                         * 3921234                               users:(("wayland-egl",pid=3260,fd=3))`

This code is using Wayland protocol to share its rendering buffer with the compositor, `gnome-shell`.  And rendering using OpenGL.  There is absolutely no way this program is running using the XWayland server process, X11 protocol, or the OpenGL ES (GLES) API.  I do not think this leaves any room for doubt.

The purpose of the `ss` test is to prove that `wayland-egl` is not connected to the X11-protocol socket which is served by the XWayland process. (process = running program). The XWayland server is a whole separate process from gnome-shell or weston. weston does not speak X11 protocol at all. XWayland does.

For contrast:

`$ glxgears >/dev/null 2>&1 &    # spinning gears appear!
$ ss --unix -a -p | grep glxgears
u_str ESTAB  0      0                                                  * 3924917                                         * 3922619                               users:(("glxgears",pid=3310,fd=3))
$ ss --unix -a -p | grep 3922619
u_str ESTAB  0      0                                                  * 3924917                                         * 3922619                               users:(("glxgears",pid=3310,fd=3))
u_str ESTAB  0      0                                 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 3922619                                         * 3924917                               users:(("Xwayland",pid=2307,fd=14))`

Also, if you set `DISPLAY=:666`, you will notice that `wayland-egl` can still run.  Whereas `xterm`, or `glxgears`, require an X11 server, and setting a bogus display number will prevent them from running.  `DISPLAY` is the standard environment variable used by all X11 clients, to know which display number to connect to.

Comment: Presumptive insults such as "Since you apparently haven't had five minutes to run these commands yourself yet..." are thoroughly unhelpful and plainly mean-spirited. *Ad hominems* only invalidate whatever argument you were attempting to make. You can do better, young Padawan.

Comment: @CecilCurry edited. Apologies for confusing you with Paradox. I'm happy to hear further criticism or positive suggestions from you or anyone else. Although I'm not doing any more *technical* work on this, unless someone actually engages with what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr answer:

EGL != OpenGL ES

EGL is a library to manage render buffers.

APIs like OpenGL, OpenGL ES or OpenVG can render into those render buffers directly.

Why does Wayland use EGL instead of an own render buffer management?

Actually Wayland has it's own render buffer (`wl_buffer`) but the internal structure is implementation dependent and for performance reasons, Wayland allows clients to directly render to the GPU framebuffer and in direct rendering mode, a render buffer model was required that allows direct rendering to screen but at the same time sharing render buffers between processes and both is possible with EGL, which already existed and was well supported, so why would Wayland not use it?

So Wayland does not always use EGL?

Wayland clients won't use EGL in indirect rendering mode. That is when clients don't directly render to the screen but to a shared memory buffer (shared between client and compositor). Yet the compositor may still use EGL to render the content of that buffer to the screen. Also when Vulkan API is used there is no EGL involved, as Vulkan does not render to EGL buffers. Vulkan can directly render to Wayland surfaces, using the `VK_KHR_wayland_surface` extension (which may somehow use EGL behind the scenes but that is none of your business).